# Как "заставить" телеграм-бота скинуть контакт?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot

Я перекопал документацию по pyTelegramBotAPI и не нашёл как телеграмм бот может отправить контакт пользователю. Я понимаю, что бот умеет отправлять файлы и т.п., но не нашёл как отправить контакт пользователя. Такое решение есть? Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Вы хотите контакт, что пользователь ранее отправлял боту, отправить другому пользователю?

Comment: Не совсем. У меня есть задача - при нажатии на кнопку бот должен отправить контакт пользователю. Альтернативным способом можно отправить ссылку на контакт или к кнопке подвязать ссылку с переходом. Но меня интересует именно может ли телеграмм бот отправить контакт пользователю?

Comment: А откуда бот должен брать контакты?

Comment: @Даниял, например, из БД

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Согласно [документации](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendcontact):

`bot.send_contact(message.chat.id, '+71234567890', 'Имя', 'Фамилия')`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]